# How to Wait the for loop in angular for the response?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to wait the for loop in angular for the response? And update the latest value of the response.

```
users: Users

getUsers(){
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
        (res: Users) => {
            this.users = res
        }
    )
}

setValue(){

    for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {

        if (this.users.length > 0) {

            break
        }

        ///some code
        this.getUsers()
    }
}
```

Comment: Loops are synchronous, just call `getUsers()` under the code of your loop.

Comment: You can use async await. If you have `API` call inside your `getUser` function.

Comment: Is there any life cycle hook is for checking the value of the property. Like onChanges.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? You're current `setValue` function doesn't do anything, if you directly `break` when `this.users.length > 0`.

Comment: How to delay a for loop?

Comment: @dany putting wait in for loop or in any iterator code in front-end part is not the optimal solution. because if you add wait in synchronous code in angular i.e. at front-end side it will halt your GUI or may be hang it. so always perform it asynchronously. try to use rxjs Observable for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call `API` inside your loop you can use async await here is the example.

```
async setValue() {
 for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
        if (this.users.length > 0) {
            break
        }
        ///some code
        await this.getUsers();
        console.log(i);  // here you can see that this line will execute after the api call is completed 
    }
}

getUsers(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
        (res: Users) => {
            this.users = res;
            resolve();
        }, err => {
            resolve();
        })
   }
 }
```

Comment: `getUsers()` it's an observable just use `toPromise()` helper